# Incorrect total average in metric table chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

[Metric Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiQQT.png)
[Correct Average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBhMr.png)
Hi, I would like to ask your assistance in solving this issue. Metric chart in power bi is not reflecting correct total average for rows as seen in the image. Thank you

Reflect correct total average for certain row in the metric chart.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how youre calculating the average, there few details in your question, but i sugest to try using DAX function AVERAGE() and see if you can use the calculation.